# Russell - Concepts vs Denotation

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, bertrand-russell

I understand why definite descriptions like 'The King of England' are denoting phrases, but I am confused by differing between concepts and what they 'denote'.

In Principles of Mathematics:

> A concept denotes when, if it occurs in a proposition, the proposition
> is not about the concept, but about a term connected in a certain
> peculiar way with the concept. If I say “I met a man,” the proposition
> is not about a man: this is a concept which does not walk the
> streets, but lives in the shadowy limbo of the logic-books. What I
> met was a thing, not a concept, an actual man with a tailor and a
> bank-account or a public-house and a drunken wife. Again, the
> proposition “any finite number is odd or even” is plainly true; yet
> the concept “any finite number” is neither odd nor even.

For example 'a man' seems equivalent to 'one man', why is this treated as denoting anything but the idea of there being a single entity and that entity being of a class 'man'?

For example, I could easily say 'one man lives next door', It is a simply a statement about how many men are next door I do not need to be using 'one man' to refer to any individual, in this case it denotes a concept.

This is different to 'The King of England' where I could argue that 'the king of england' is a person and the idea of what it is to be the king of england is a different entity which needs it's own reference.

Do these phrases have two meanings and what is the difference between the concepts and what they denote?
Take 'two' does it have a concept and denotion because it's denotation is a concept?

With 'The king of England', I could suggest that the only 'concept' it gives me is that of the man, the denotation in this case which to me is clearly a particular person.

Clearly I am misunderstanding, but I'd appreciate if anyone could suggest where, and if there is other sources for which I can clear up my confusion.

Comment: @Confused, perhaps it's not so much that "a man" refers to a thing or encodes a description that can go on to be satisfied by a thing; not so much that "a man" does either of those things *unless we use it to do so*. But so see ["Rule-following and Intentionality"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rule-following/).

Comment: so 'a man' can refer to a concept, or an object/person? For example, 'a man' as a concept or 'a man walked across the road'? Is a phrase like 'a man' denoting the *concept* if given in isolation? Perhaps the property of a 'description' is that it denotes other things but the concept is more related to it than itself?

Comment: @Confused, Russell thought, IIRC, that names were implicit descriptions, which refer indirectly, via a "satisfaction" relation. This is opposed to the theory that names refer directly (the Millian/Kripkean view, I think), by a sort of "baptism." C.f., then, though, Frege's view that, "*X* exists," is shorthand for, "The concept of *X* is instantiated."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA 'a man' can refer to a concept, or an object/person? For example, 'a man' as a concept or 'a man walked across the road'? Is a phrase like 'a man' denoting the concept if given in isolation?

Comment: @KristianBerry I see the usage of 'concept' is not as simple in this case that is probably my issue

Comment: Some preliminary comment (do be developed, maybe...) Russell's language in PoM is a little bit tricky: he is not very clear in the distinction between an expression of the language and what the reference/meaning of that expression is. See the post [What does Russell mean by "term" in Principles of Mathematics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/what-does-russell-mean-by-term-in-principles-of-mathematics/30942#30942). When Russell writes (p.21): "the class of *terms* belonging to each of the classes..." he is speaking of objects belonging to *classes*.

Comment: Thus, when he writes (§56): "A concept denotes when, if it occurs in a proposition, the proposition is not about the concept, but about a term connected in a certain peculiar way with the concept." he is speaking of the "object" *concept* used to speak about a certain term (another object").

Comment: The example about “I met a man” wants to show that the concept *man* is used here not to refer to the universal (the universal *man*  is a "concept which does not walk the streets, but lives in the shadowy limbo of the logic-books") but to refer to a particular (an individual man) not specified by way of the proper name.

Comment: See also [On Denoting (1905)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Denoting): "By a `denoting phrase' I mean a phrase such as any one of the following: a man, some man, any man, every man, all men, the present King of England, the present King of France, the center of mass of the solar system at the first instant of the twentieth century, the revolution of the earth round the sun, the revolution of the sun round the earth. Thus a phrase is denoting solely in virtue of its form."

Comment: "A phrase may denote ambiguously; e.g. `a man' denotes not many men, but an ambiguous man." Consider specifically the example: "all men"; what Russell asserts is that this expression has some sort of "reference" but this is not the universal *man* (humanity). So, what is it?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was wrong in that 'a man' is not a proper name for the concept of there being a single entity and that be a man, neither is truthfully 'one man', it is a 'description' of that idea/any entity that is instantiated by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The king of England" is not always a denoting expression. In a sentence like "the king of England has always had the power to dissolve Parliament", the phrase "the king of England" does not denote a particular; it's meaning is a concept.

Similarly, the phrase "a man" may denote or may not denote depending on context. In a sentence like "She needs a man", the the phrase "a man" does not denote; there is no particular man that it is referring to. However the phrase still has meaning. You can still look at particulars and say whether a given particular is a man or not. We describe this situation by saying that the *meaning* (not the *denotation*) of the phrase "a man" in this context is a concept.

On the other hand, in a sentence like "She went out with a man last night", the phrase "a man" denotes a particular man--the one she went out with last night. In this case, for consistency, we still say that the *meaning* of the phrase "a man" is still a concept--the concept of being the man she went out with last night--but that the denotation of the phrase is the man himself.

You can't tell from the mere form of a noun phrase whether it denotes or not. For example, some people claim Jesus never existed. If he did exist then "Jesus" denotes. If he did not exist, then "Jesus" does not denote.

But it's worse than that; from the form of a phrase you can't tell even whether it is intended to denote, not even a proper noun. For example, suppose it rains and you say "Mother Nature didn't want us to play baseball today". The phrase "Mother Nature" is a proper noun, but in this context it is not intended to denote.

Furthermore, even if a phrase denotes, the denotation may not relevant to the intent of the speaker in uttering the sentence. This may be the case for "One man lives next door". If your intention is simply to convey the number and sexes of your neighbors, then the phrase "one man" in that context may denote a particular, but the particular is not relevant to the utterance. What is relevant is the concept of being one man, which is the meaning of the phrase, not its denotation.

Comment: Re first statement: correct, but the well-known Russell's analysis is about "the present King of ...".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, True, but I was responding to a quote in the question.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I was wrong in that 'a man' is not a proper name for the concept of there being a single entity and that be a man, neither is truthfully 'one man', it is a 'description' of that idea/any entity that is instantiated by it. In this way can something have 'meaning' of this concept without denoting it?

Comment: @DavidGudeman if 'one man' is the meaning of the phrase, does this imply that the phrase itself cannot directly be used to denote the meaning? The distinction between 'meaning' and 'denotation' is not necessarily clear.

Comment: based on Russell, would something like '2' denote an idea or mean an idea?

Comment: @Confused A phrase does not denote a meaning; it expresses a meaning (a meaning is a concept). If it denotes, then it denotes the particular that it refers to or points at. A meaning is always a concept, never a particular. A denotation is always a particular (although, I suppose there are phrases that denote concepts like "the concept of being a man". I'm not sure how to describe that one).

Comment: @DavidGudeman I apologise to bump, but I wonder what we would say about phrases like 'if I had a dog, I would walk it' do 'a dog' and 'it' denote or is this a strange case?

Comment: Is there some dog in the real world that you can point to and say, "That's the dog I'm talking about?" If not, then it doesn't denote.

Comment: This answer mistakes [denotation and reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotation). "Although they have similar meanings, denotation should not be confused with reference... A reference is a specific person, place, or thing that a speaker identifies when using a word... For referring expressions, the denotation of the phrase is most likely the phrase's referent. For content words, the denotation of the word can refer to any object, real or imagined, to which the word could be applied." A meaningful phrase always denotes, but it might not refer. Such is the case with hypothetical dogs.

Comment: @JD, that sounds like a quote from a Meinongian.

Comment: My understanding of the convention is: [Denote according to MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denote) is just a verb to show something entails [signifier-signified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signified_and_signifier). What is signified can be anything. Frege's claim to fame is to argue that the signified can be Sinn or Bedeutung (sense or reference). Thus 'dog' denotes both the idea of dog (sense, Sinn) and my pet (reference, Bedeutung). Meinong would simply argue that dog-as-idea and dog-as-my-pet both have types of existence, Sosein and Sein resp.

Comment: Denotation can also be established by extension in which specific instances are specified: 'Dog' is the idea of dog, the class of all dogs, or a specific dog in the class' or by intention which uses rules: 'Dog' includes concepts, categories, or specific references to animals which meet the biological criteria worthy of inclusion in the genus *Canis*. I don't think you can find a reliable reference to contradict these statements about the convention about the use denote, sense, and reference.

Comment: But I do see that Robinson uses denote and connote slightly different than modern usage regarding emotional content. He says in *Definition* on page 109 "Thus by the 'denotation' of a given word I usually mean roughly EITHER all the particular things to which it is applied OR all the classes which include all and only the particular things to which it is applied" (emph mine). Here he seems to split not on real and imaginary but universal and particular... he in the next paragraph keeps the door open to interpretation by saying...

Comment: "I do not wish to define precisely how I am going to use the words... "denotation' or to confine myself to a single rigid usage. I think the general thrust in the canon is it's important to keep the notions of existence separate from those of signifying. You have references which contradict this, that would be great.

Comment: I would consider whether you are conflating universal and particular with fictional and real. We often draw a notion of universal from a class or real particulars, but that's not a necessity. We can draw univerals from classes of fictional particulars, such as the notion that "imaginary animals frequently occur in mythology such as pegasus in Greek mythology, Fenris in Norse mythology, Tiamat in Babylonian mythology". The last example gets to a universal from fictional particulars, that is particulars without physical referents.

Comment: @JD, in Sinn or Bedeutung, "Bedeutung" is often translated "denotation". That is, "denotation" is contrasted with "sense" rather than with "connotation". I've read no philosopher who uses the word "connotation" in a technical sense and my impressions is that it is a term of linguistics rather than philosophy. Maybe those who use "connotation" and "denotation" use the word "denotation" in a different sense than it is used by analytic philosophers.

Comment: From SEP's article on Frege: According to Frege "a mathematical expression such as ‘22’ denotes the result of applying the function ()2 to the number 2 as argument, namely, the number 4. Similarly, the expression ‘7+1’ denotes the result of applying the binary function +((),()) to the numbers 7 and 1 as arguments, in that order." Clearly Frege, the founder of analytic philosophy didn't require reified objects at all since he denoted functions as the meaning of expressions. We do that to this day in CS in [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics)...

Comment: I've made my case that denotation, the act of showing the origin of meaning, appeals to both reference and sense, both of which are types of meanings and quoted from three sources one of which appeals to Frege. Future readers are free to decide what analytical philosophers do.

Comment: @JD "I'm beginning to wonder if you think I denied that abstract objects can be denoted. I didn't deny that. Also, when you give the semantics of a programming language by assigning mathematical denotations to language elements, that's denotational semantics, not operational semantics. Your wikipedia link says so in the first paragraph.

Comment: Hah! "Operational semantics is a category of formal programming language semantics in which certain desired properties of a program, such as correctness, safety or security, are verified by constructing proofs from logical statements about its execution and procedures, rather than by attaching mathematical meanings to its terms (denotational semantics)." The difference between mathematical denotations and programmatic denotations is relative since mathematical programs are both both in that the syntaxes are almost identical, but also in that Howard-Curry makes them isomorphic...

Comment: But I'll concede there's a rabbit hole in which you can continue your disputation.

Comment: @JD, operational semantics doesn't usually involve assigning any denotations to terms. Your own links says: "rather than by attaching mathematical meanings to its terms". This is what happens when you try to argue about a topic you aren't familiar with and try to use wikipedia and google to shore up your lack: you end up misunderstanding things and revealing your lack of knowledge. I've done graduate-level research in denotational semantics and published my results in TOPLAS. Trust me. I know what denotations are.